# Linq: Select Distinct and Order

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have the following....

```
Dim dc as New DBDataContext
Dim q = From c In dc.Customers _
    Order By c.City _
    Select c.City _
    Distinct
```

My problem is that although the query produces a distinct list it is not sorted. How do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If q is your unsorted query, then you can sort it afterwards

```
Dim sorted = From c in q order by c select c
```

or

```
q = From c in q order by c select c
```

Answer (score 1):

Will moving `Order By c.City` after `Distinct` fix it?

```
Dim q = From c In dc.Customers _
    Select c.City _
    Distinct _
    Order By City
```

or if above doesn't work you can do ordering operation in client :

```
Dim result = q.OrderBy(Function(x) x)
```

Comment: Sorry, first option is not allowed in Linq and the second option I'm afraid you have lost me on the Function(x) x bit...

Comment: updated my first option syntax. And about the 2nd, it is lambda expression. `Function(x)` means declare item in `q` as `x` (in this case it is City), then select `x` as parameter of `OrderBy` function. In short "order by `x`", which means "order by City".

Comment: about [Lambda Expression in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Comment: what if i want to order as numbers not strings